# Changing bevel modifier

Tags: modeling, bevel

My bevel panel in add modifier pa is like this and I want to change it like this.  Because many of the settings and tutorials I saw are done with this type of panel. I'm confused. What should I do?
[image: I want to change it to this mode]

Comment: You are using a quite old version of Blender (2.80.75), the current stable version is 3.4.1 right now. In newer versions the modifier looks different. You cannot simply switch the appearance from old to new version, this is not a "mode".

Comment: My computer is very old and uses Windows 7 32 bit.‍♀️ How can I update this program?

Comment: Please don't post images of your computer screen! Blender has a built-in method of saving images via its Window > Save screenshot menu. Having said that, your image shows that you're using a very old version of Blender (2.80). Any tutorials you watch will probably be using version 2.93 or above (the latest is currently 3.4) and the layout of the interface and modifiers have changed significantly since the version you are using.

Comment: I'm noob and I didn't even know how to take a screenshot, so I posted a picture from my computer I'm sorry.But what can I do with this old version that can't do anything right?

Comment: @Narges Ng: older versions, unless bugged, **do** things **right** as well. It all depends on your needs. If you want to be a Blender pro or a new feature enthusiast download the most recent version your hardware is sufficient for and upgrade it if it's necessary. The download site is blender.org

Answer (score 0):

The picture on the right side is the newest version of blender. It means you need to update your blender to 3.0.0 or above.

Comment: My computer is very old and uses Windows 7 32 bit. How can I update this program?

Comment: You can't. The last version available in 32-bit was 2.8.

Comment: But in version 3 and above, the panel changes to this mode.right?

Comment: Yes that's it, but anyway it doesn't change a lot of things

Comment: Ok, i found that blender 2.91 also has this mode. But unfortunately it doesn't support windows7 32bit. One solution is to compile blender by yourself.

Comment: @NargesNg Well, it is like that. If you don't have a 64-bit system, unfortunately your version 2.80 is the last that supported 32-bit Windows. But anyway, the modifier is not in a different mode, it's mostly just a reworked UI there. If you look at the options, you can set all the same things in your version that are available in the old version.

Comment: I  just want do copy to selected in add modifier and bevel panel but I can't...my work is incompleted

Comment: In the 3D view, hit Ctrl-L > Modifiers to copy the modifiers to your selected object.